# 'module' object is not callable when I call values in dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

when I call the values in the dictionary d, I get such error:`'module' object is not callable`
this is how I use the values in d:

```
d = {'c1': (10,20), 'c2': (30,20), 'c3': (10,30), 'c4': (10,40)}

import math
import random

because there are two values for one key, I just need one random value of them, so I use random.choice, then I get the error:
'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'choice'
can somebody help me with this part?

time1=-random.choice(d['c1'])* math.log(1.0 - random())
time2=-random.choice(d['c2'])* math.log(1.0 - random())
time3=-random.choice(d['c3'])* math.log(1.0 - random())
time4=-random.choice(d['c4'])* math.log(1.0 - random())
```

Update:
I just need to change random() to random.random() to calculate time1

Comment: `random` is a module, just like `math`.  You can call functions defined *in* a module, like you did with `math.log`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because there's a `random` function in the module called `random`. When you call `import random` you make `random` module visible to the code, but not `random` function.

Try this (line 4 makes the difference):

```py
>>> d = {'c1': 10, 'c2': 20, 'c3': 40, 'c4': 8}
>>> 
>>> import math
>>> from random import random
>>> 
>>> time1=-d['c1']* math.log(1.0 - random())
>>> time2=-d['c2']* math.log(1.0 - random())
>>> time3=-d['c3']* math.log(1.0 - random())
>>> time4=-d['c4']* math.log(1.0 - random())
>>> time1
16.376979481808323
```

I would also suggest reading more about modules: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html

and execution model: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/executionmodel.html

Answer (score 1):

It's all about `random` which is a module. You can't call a module, but a function provided in a module. In my opinion, you need to replace `random()` with `random.randint(a, b)`. Anyway, you can find all supported functions [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html) from the documentation.